# Batch File that backs up user's data when no one is logged in

Tags: batch-file, backup

I am trying to make a batch file that backs up user data when no one is logged in. I created one that works fine when a user is logged in using the %USERNAME% variable, but I would like the backup to run at night when no one is logged in. Ideally the backup would copy a users Documents, Desktop, and Outlook Data File to a shared network drive or USB drive. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it _should_ work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to answer the question of which user's data should be copied when no one is logged in. Remember that Windows is a multi-user operating system, even if you've only created one account.

The reason everything works fine when you run the batch file as a particular user is because it just copies the data for that user.

To make it run when no one is logged in, you can set the batch file up as a Scheduled Task and specify a particular user account under which it should run.

Of course, this will only back up data for *one* user. If you want to backup data for *all* users, you might be better off copying the entire Users subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I did think about that, and I have a few ideas on how to fix it. First, is there a way to check to see who the last person to log in was? Each PC that I need to back up has one primary user, so the last user to log in should be the profile that I want to backup but I am not sure how to get that value in a batch file. My second option would be to backup the whole user directory, however this is wasteful because off all the extra data that would be backed up.

Comment: I don't think there's a programmatic way to find the last user logged in, but you might start with the computer's name as a basis. You could build a simple "IF" tree to determine who the user is expected to be...

(Not valid code... just a bad example to demonstrate!)
`if %COMPUTERNAME%="Sales1" copy c:\users\salesman\*.* c:\backup\ /r`